# How to upload folders and sub folders to an internal snowflake stage

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I need help uploading folders and sub folders with XML documents to a Snowflake internal stage.

The folders are laid out like this - XML is the main folder then there are about 200 sub folders in the XML folder with about 3000 files in each of those folders. I want to upload all of these XML files.

I use the following command in snow sql but will have to modify it obviously:

put file://XML/*.* @clinical parallel=10;

Comment: Did you try using a wildcard?  `put file://XML/* @clinical parallel=10;` ?  Note, the syntax of the file path in the documentation, as well.  You'll need to reference more than what you and I have in our examples.

Comment: That seemed to have maybe worked - but now my command window is just sitting there after I hit enter. Its been doing this for an hour now. It didnt error out or anything. Any ideas?

Comment: should have done with smallest sub directories to test..

Comment: go to the web ui, and run the `LIST` command so see how many file have loaded (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/list.html) or open another snowsql connection and do the same..

Comment: Not sure whether SnowSQL encrypts and sends each file one at a time, or whether it encrypts ALL of the files and then sends them.  So, you might just be seeing the work that is being done locally before the transmit.

Comment: I ran that list command and nothing comes back - empty row. Its just stuck in the CMD prompt like nothing is happening.